# Validation for phone and mobile numbers

Tags: regex, validation, mobile

I tried it on Google but not get proper RE.will someone help me to achieve this :
Phone Number: (Country Code)-(City Code)-(Number)
Mobile Number: (Country Code)-(Number)

obviously that should not take char.
Please help me

Comment: Do you want to allow any country code? Is a "+" required as a prefix if there is a country code? Are country codes optional? Do you want to impose restrictions on the separators (dashes, slashes, spaces or more)? Why do you have parentheses around the parts of phone numbers - do you require them there? So, please clarify your requirements. Best also include some examples what you do and don't want to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the site for **[regular expression](http://regexlib.com)**. note it down for future reference, you won't ever be dissapointed

For phone numbers: [**http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone%20number**](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone%20number)

now here are some samples from there

**PhoneNumbers**

- ^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
- (((\d{3}) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}
- (([0-9]{2}|0{1}((x|[0-9]){2}[0-9]{2})))\s*[0-9]{3,4}[- ]*[0-9]{4}

**Mobiles:**

- ^[+]447\d{9}$
- ^(+44\s?7\d{3}|(?07\d{3})?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$

Hope it helps